# ionic 3 / cordova plugin file / iOS / file access

Tags: ios, angular, ionic3

I have developed an app that allows you to open and edit Office files (.docx) in Word. In order for the app and Word to have appropriate permissions on iOS, I set the option "LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace" to YES in my info.plist file.
What I also want is that I can share files directly from the Files app into my app. However, with iOS the option "Share to 'myApp'" does not work anymore as soon as I set "LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace" to YES but only "Open in 'myApp'". And that's exactly where the problem lies when I pass the passed file path to Plugin File.
Without "LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace" I get the following path:

> file: ///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/300F9E3A-2E17-4330-8F88-12855269CCA8/tmp/com.my.app-Inbox/Dokument.docx

The plugin file recognizes the path and I can do anything else with the file I want.

But with set option "LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace" to YES I get the following path:

> file: ///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/304CFCDB-227B-4149-9F87-078B341F7A00/Documents/Dokument.docx

And the plugin file returns the error: "NOT_FOUND_ERROR"

Is there a way that works both? The parts function from FILES and the permission to edit documents out of the app?

**EDIT:**

```
import {File} from '@ionic-native/file'

...


constructor(public file: File) {
}

this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav, {}).subscribe(
           (match) => {

               this.storeFile(match.$link.url);
            }

            }, (nomatch) => {

            });

storeFile(filepath) {

    this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(filepath)
        .then((entry) => {
            console.log(entry);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e)
        })
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
storeFile(filepath) {

   this.file.resolveDirectoryUrl(path1)

        .then((entry) => {

            console.log('+++++++++++++++', entry);

            this.file.checkDir(entry.nativeURL, '')
                .then((dir) => {
                    console.log('+++++++++++++++ dir', dir);

                    this.file.listDir(entry.nativeURL, '')
                        .then((list) => {
                            console.log('+++++++++++++++ list', list);
                        })
                        .catch((e) => {
                            console.log('--------------- list', e) // <--- NOT_FOUND_ERROR
                        })
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    console.log('--------------- dir', e)
                })

        }, (e) => {
            console.log('---------------', e)
        });
}
```

Comment: Ca you add some code how you are getting path ? or plugin related code?

Comment: i have edited my post above

Comment: it looks like I have access to the folder stub (this.file.resolveDirectoryUrl (pathwithoutfilename)), but when I try to read a file (this.file.listDir (pathwithoutfilename.nativeURL, "")) I get the Error NOT_FOUND_ERR